Connecting ESP32 IDF MQTT5 Example to HIVEHQ
I am using the IDF MQTT5 example project, and have built it unmodified and can connect to Mosquito

I (47716) mqtt5_example: Other event id:7 I (47726) main_task:
Returned from app_main() I (49036) mqtt5_example: MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED

I now want to change the broker to HIVEHQ but am battling to get the HIVHQ URI accepted.
I have opened an account at HIVEHQ and can connect and use it successfully with a Python Paho test app I wrote using MQTT5 and TLS so I know the broker side is good.
I started by changing the line:
.broker.address.uri = CONFIG_BROKER_URL,

to my hive URI
.broker.address.uri = "d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud",

It seems the URI cannot be passed in this format and my logs show:
[Codebox=text file=Untitled.txt]E (27296) mqtt_client: Error parse uri = d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud[/Codebox]
or this format
.broker.address.uri = "mqtt://d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud",

my logs:
E (39766) esp-tls: [sock=54] select() timeout
E (39766) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection: 32774
E (39766) mqtt_client: Error transport connect
So I tried commenting out
// .broker.address.uri = CONFIG_BROKER_URL,

and adding
.broker.address.hostname = "d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud",
.broker.address.port = 8883,
.broker.address.transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_TCP,

my logs:
E (21096) mqtt_client: esp_mqtt_handle_transport_read_error: transport_read(): EOF
E (21096) mqtt_client: esp_mqtt_handle_transport_read_error: transport_read() error: errno=128
So I went back to eclipse broker and tried:

.broker.address.uri = CONFIG_BROKER_URL,
.broker.address.port = 8883,
.broker.address.transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_TCP, my logs: W (30676) mqtt_client: Transport config set, but overridden by scheme

from URI: transport = 1, uri scheme = mqtt E (30686) mqtt5_client:
Client was not initialized

Can someone please help with a working solution for my HIVEHQ account
Thanks

HiveMQ Cloud is only available with encryption (TLS/SSL) so the URI would be something like mqtts://d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883 (or, if not using a URI, transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_SSL). You may find this example useful.

Thanks for your reply.  Per my notes above IDF can't parse this URI format, it returns: E (27296) mqtt_client: Error parse uri = d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud.  I am using the MQTT5 example from the same github repository

d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud is not a URI, mqtts://d72b0b51da08402e86d06db5db25f244.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud is (i.e. to be valid the scheme, mqtts in this case, is needed). In your question you tried mqtt://... but that will not work because the server is expecting an encrypted connection (so the s is needed)..

Thanks for this. I copied my example from my Python Paho test app which worked. I missed the big "S" when adding MQTT, so thanks for this. It now starts but fails to connect with No server verification option set in esp_tls_cfg_t structure. I now see there is a SSL example in MQTT, wheras I have been working on MQTT 5 example.  I will try to work though this and if necessary open a new question for clarity.  Thanks again.

I managed to get this going.  Heres how for future reference for others:
I went to the MQTT/SSL example first and followed the instructions without any modifications but could not get it to connect to the Mosquitto broker.
It turns out the certificate in the example is the problem and I think may not be a root certificate. Anyway Mosquito didn't like it.
I replace the project default CA certificate (mqtt_eclipseprojects_io.pem) contents with the Root CA certificate I got from: https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem 1. I left the same certificate name (mqtt_eclipseprojects_io.pem) so I didn’t have to make any changes to the code.
From this I could connect the MQTT/SSL project to the Mosquitto broker using SSL.
I then returned to my MQTT5 project and added the certificate code etc from the MQTT SSL example.
I added my login credentials ID and Password.
And then everything worked.
